# How to call django view onclick then redirect

Tags: javascript, python, django, redirect, searchbar

I'm trying to make a searchbar in my django app. When I click on a result from the searchbar I want it to call my view. I want the view to keep the context from what was clicked, perform a function, and then redirect me.

In my views.py

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        sp = SpotipyConnection(client_id=sp_client_id, client_secret=sp_client_secret)
        #context = {'search': sp.searchbar(query)}
        context = {'search': sp.songSearch(query)}
        return render(request,'main/search.html',context=context)
    return render(request,'main/search.html',{})

def search_results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #TODO how do i get the context of what was clicked 
        songName = None
        songArtist = None
        context = openAISearch(artist=songArtist,song=songName)
        return render(request,'main/search_results.html',context=context)
```

In my search.html:

````
{% block title %}
Search
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<script>
  function redirectToHome(songName, songArtist) {
     <!-- TODO how do I call my search_results function then return the redirect -->
  }
  </script>

<form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="search-input">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  
    </form>
  {% if search %}
  {% for result in search %}

<p onclick="redirectToHome({{ result.name }},{{ result.artists.0.name }})"> {{result.name}} by {{ result.artists.0.name }} <img src="{{ result.album.images.0.url }}" alt="{{result.name}} image" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"> </p> 
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}```
````

Comment: in `url.py` this `search` url is assigned to `def search(request)` isn't it?

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva yeah the urls are set up correctly. The search itself works but idk how to link it to the view

Answer (score 1):

try this inside js function inside html. it uses ajax to send post request

`<script> function redirectToHome(songName, songArtist) { $.ajax({ url: '/search-results/', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', data: { 'songName': songName, 'songArtist': songArtist } }); } </script>`

in views.py's `search_requests` you can get content by:
`request.POST.get('songName')` and `request.POST.get('songArtist')`

eventually return can look like this `return render(request,'main/search_results.html',context=context)` but if you need redirection you can use `return redirect(to='needed/url?query=string')` with query string to pass data you need to pass